# Django request.GET.get() always returns "None"

Tags: regex, django

I have a URL: `http://localhost:8000/submit_workout/2/`

This URL was created with: `r'^submit_workout/(?P<wr_id>\d+)/$'`

I am trying to retrieve "wr_id" when a form on that page is submitted.

I'm trying: `wr_id = request.GET.get('wr_id',None)` and am expecting **wr_id=2** but keep getting **wr_id=None** returned.

Any thoughts? I am new to programming/django and really appreciate your time and expertise.

Comment: it must be `wr_id = request.POST.get('wr_id',None)` but please post the entire codes so that I can understand the flow of your codes.

Comment: :)) you get it None coz you dont have any http get parameter wr_id in the url, that has nothing to do with the regex in urlpattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL params, which are named in the url regex, can be passed as arguments to your method which handles the request. If your dispatcher looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^submit_workout/(?P<wr_id>\d+)/$', 'submit_workout'),
```

Then your method should look like this:

```
def submit_workout(request, wr_id):
```

and `wr_id` can be accessed directly.

If you want `wr_id` to be a GET variable, then your url should look like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/submit_workout?wr_id=2
```